# How to set up a github pull request build in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

So, I've been using Jenkins for quite a while.  I have set up numerous projects with the Github Pull Request Builder plugin to run tests whenever someone opens a pull request, and then trigger some other job (build, push, deploy, etc) whenever the pull request actually gets merged to master.

So, is there any way to set this up with a Jenkinsfile, or the organization folders, or the multibranch build deal?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [github-organization-folder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Organization+Folder+Plugin) plugin in combination with the [multi-branch plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multi-Branch+Project+Plugin) plugin offers exactly this awesome feature: It scans a whole organization (optionally restricted to certain patterns in repo/branch names) for `Jenkinsfile`s and automatically adds jobs. This also happens for Pull Requests.

Once the PR is closed, it automatically removes the job.

<strike>To avoid arbitrary code execution, an organization member has to trigger building the job (same as for the GPRB plugin). The phrase can be configured in the *Jenkins System* settings.</strike>

EDIT: Under the *Advanced* section in Jenkins, you find options about what types of PR you want to build. If you build fork PRs, then there's afaik no way to prevent running code without prior inspecting it.

---

An example, how this looks like:

[image: PR on Github]

---

[image: PR in Jenkins]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I just realized that the pull request builds are build into the multi-branch plugin- it is not mentioned anywhere in the docs :)  Still need to figure out how to do something different for pull request builds, but I think that is just programming.

Comment: You can check `env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith('PR-')` if you wish to behave differently on PR builds.

Comment: or `env.CHANGE_ID != null`

Comment: (updated my answer to include the multi-branch plugin)

Comment: I actually did the opposite and did if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master'), but this answer helped me a ton!

Comment: Could you provide a example of setting commit status? I tried but no luck :(

Comment: This happens automatically.

Comment: The https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Organization+Folder+Plugin page says that this plugin is now obsolete but does not mention an alternative.

Comment: This functionality has been moved to the [GitHub Branch Source Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin).

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau cannot confirm this. Please open up a new question, check the Jenkins issue tracker or ask in other channels with configuration details.

Comment: I read this answer and reviewed on the provided links but it's still not clear to me *how* to set this up.  There are also comments about how you can check `check env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith('PR-')` - but where is this done?  Is this in a Jenkinsfile?  If so, can we see a sample Jenkinsfile gist?  Thanks.