# Diffrence between buildflow, multijob and pipeline plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

what is the difference between buildflow, multijob and pipeline plugin.
If i have jobs need to run on the same node sequentially, which one should i use and why?
I have some parameters that are to be shared by all the jobs. I can do it using  multijob and build flow also. which one is preferable?
I am confused.

Comment: This is not really a stackoverflow question, please refer to the "How to ask":
How to Ask
Is your question about programming?
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Share your research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Pipeline plugin.

From the [Build Flow plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin):

"Deprecated: Users should migrate to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin"

If you're starting from scratch, the answer is basically the same for the Multijob plugin (prefer the pipeline plugin). The Multijob plugin was created pre-jenkins-2, and the pipeline plugin has implemented much of its functionality. Pipeline is one of the default plugins and is being actively maintained by multiple developers. Here is [someone migrating from Multijob to Pipeline in 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37744355/6090676).